# Crowdfunding Contract like Kickstarter

Tags: metamask, crowdsale, error

I was following a tutorial for a Crowdfunding Smart Contract that acts like Kickstarter from Programtheblockchain, however I'm always getting a MetaMask Error which says "Exception thrown in Contract Code" when trying to send Ether to the Contract. It compiles and deploys just fine, but I can't send Ether to it. Is the code maybe outdated or am I doing something wrong on my end?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract Crowdfunding {
    address owner;
    uint256 deadline;
    uint256 goal;
    mapping(address => uint256) public pledgeOf;

    function Crowdfunding(uint256 numberOfDays, uint256 _goal) public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        deadline = now + (numberOfDays * 1 days);
        goal = _goal;
    }

    function pledge(uint256 amount) public payable {
        require(now < deadline);                // in the fundraising period
        require(msg.value == amount);

        pledgeOf[msg.sender] += amount;
    }

    function claimFunds() public {
        require(address(this).balance >= goal); // funding goal met
        require(now >= deadline);               // in the withdrawal period
        require(msg.sender == owner);

        msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    function getRefund() public {
        require(address(this).balance < goal);  // funding goal not met
        require(now >= deadline);               // in the withdrawal period

        uint256 amount = pledgeOf[msg.sender];
        pledgeOf[msg.sender] = 0;
        msg.sender.transfer(amount);
    }
}
```

And my deployment code

```
var Crowdfunding = artifacts.require("Crowdfunding");

module.exports = function(deployer){
    const numberOfDays = 1;
    const goal = web3.toWei(10, 'ether');   
deployer.deploy(Crowdfunding, numberOfDays, goal);
};
```

Comment: Where exactly do you deploy the contract and where is your Metamask connected? Is it Mainnet, Rinkeby, or local development environment?

Comment: Cool, looks like we're getting somewhere :) I remember having error messages like this when I forgot to update contract related files in the web app after updating and re-deploying the contract.

Comment: For now I'm just using the Ganache + MetaMask combination to test the Contract, so I don't have a web app just yet, or what do you mean with the web app? Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here :)  But yes, I have seen these kinds of errors and they were fixable by resetting the account in MetaMask or re-compiling / deploying, but this time nothing seems to fix the issue unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Your contract does not have a fallback `payable` function. The only `payable` function you have is the `pledge` function which is not a fallback function.

Therefore, if you are only trying to send Ether to the contract without explicitly calling the `pledge` function your transaction will fail as the contract cannot accept Ether without explicit call to the `pledge` function.

You can read more about fallback function here: https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/solidity-fallback-functions/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that may be going wrong here:

1. If you are only sending Ether (without adding any additional data), it will not work because you don't have a fallback function (`function ()`). I suggest adding a fallback function to your code.
2. Your `amount` may not be equivalent to the `msg.value`. Remember, `msg.value` is in Wei, so if you are trying to send 1 Ether, then `msg.value == 1000000000000000000` Wei. On a side note, is there a reason you have the line `require(msg.value == amount);`, instead of simply using `msg.value` in the line below it?

Comment: Yes. Prior to the `require` statement, you can add `amount = amount * 1 ether`, provided that the amount you pass in will always in in Ether. (see [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html))